# Wordpress - Cannot spoof UA for responsive theme

Tags: wordpress, mobile, themes, user-agent

I'm currently trying to make some CSS changes to the mobile edition of a website using the Wordpress theme [Responsive by ThemeID](http://themeid.com/responsive-theme/). I've spoofed my user agent to a Samsung Android, but this site still displays as if it were a desktop. When viewing it on an actual mobile device, the theme changes.

I'm sure I've spoofed my UA correctly because Google, Youtube, Yahoo, MSN, Stack Overflow, etc. all respond to my browser being mobile. Does this theme not really have a mobile view or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theme format is controlled by CSS media queries. No need to forge a UA, just resize your desktop window to a narrower width to invoke the mobile view.

Comment: I wasn't aware media queries even existed. Resizing my window worked just fine. Thank you.

Comment: There's a "Resize Window" extension for Chrome that lets you easily jump back and forth between mobile (e.g., 320x480) and desktop window sizes.

Comment: @PhilN. Chrome has another built in feature to automate this, click the gear in the bottom right of the inspect panel and you can override the UA, device metrics and font scale factor from the Overrides tab.

Answer (score 0):

Theme indeed uses Media Queries breakpoints and they will adjust and adapt the layout to any* viewing environment.

Responsive breakpoints are:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {}
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {}
@media screen and (max-width: 240px) {}
```

Thanks,
Emil Uzelac

P.S. We have a dedicated [support forum](http://themeid.com/forum/), just in case that further assistance is needed.